# Python lxml - returns null list

Tags: python, python-2.7, screen-scraping, lxml

I cannot figure out what is wrong with the XPATH when trying to extract a value from a webpage table. The method seems correct as I can extract the page title and other attributes, but I cannot extract the third value, it always returns an empty list?

```
from lxml import html
import requests

test_url = 'SC312226'

page = ('https://www.opencompany.co.uk/company/'+test_url)

print 'Now searching URL: '+page

data = requests.get(page)
tree = html.fromstring(data.text)

print tree.xpath('//title/text()') # Get page title  
print tree.xpath('//a/@href') # Get href attribute of all links  
print tree.xpath('//*[@id="financial"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div[2]/text()')
```

Unless i'm missing something, it would appear the XPATH is correct:

[Chrome screenshot](http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2014-08-18_at_16.51.15-UCchvYNU.png)

I checked Chrome console, appears ok! So i'm at a loss

```
$x ('//*[@id="financial"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div[2]/text()')
[
"£432,272"
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify element name. If you don't want specify specific tag name, you can use `*`:

```
print tree.xpath('//*[@id="financial"]/...')
                    ^
```

**UPDATE**

In the html file (just the html before the rendering in the browser), there's no tbody tag. So you need to remove `tbody` from the expression:

```
//*[@id="financial"]/table/tr/td[1]/table/tr[2]/td[1]/div[2]/text()
```

Alternative way using `following-sibling` axis:

```
//div[text()="Total Assets"]/following-sibling::div/text()
```

Comment: Tried that, still no joy.  Empty list.

Comment: Thanks!  It now returns, but it returns the following value:     [u'\xa3447']
Do I need to decode it someway?

Comment: @ChrisFinlayson if you fetch an item and print it, you will get what you want.

Comment: Adding this to the print statement formats the output correctly:   `print unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', tree.xpath('//*[@id="financial"]/table/tr/td[1]/table/tr[2]/td[1]/div[2]/text()')[0]).encode('ascii','ignore')`

Comment: @ChrisFinlayson, You don't need to call `unicodedata.normalize` and `encode` at all. printing the first item should just work. See this:  http://asciinema.org/a/11579