# Xpath with lxml returns empty string, selenium works ok

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, lxml

I have used `selenium` and `find_element_by_xpath` to extract some text from webpages. I have managed to get this working successfully on my laptop.  However, I need to run the code in Google Colab
and so I cannot use selenium (there is no Firefox or Chrome in Colab and I get a geckodriver error which makes sense). `lxml` looks promising and I have managed to get it working on a couple of the values, but 
some value are just not in the extracted html (weird) and therefore the returned string is empty.

Dropping 'tbody' in one of the xpaths helped in one instance, as per this SO answer: [Python lxml - returns null list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367339/python-lxml-returns-null-list) but then there are a couple of cells like the game date that come back empty.

THIS WORKED ON LAPTOP WITH SELENIUM (XPATHS FROM FIREFOX):

```
from selenium import webdriver

URL = 'https://www.soccer24.com/match/C4RB2hO0/#match-summary'

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(URL)

Selenium_TeamA_working = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/span/a').text
print('Team A using selenium: ' + Selenium_TeamA_working)
```

THIS KIND OF WORKS WITH LXML BUT RETURNS A NULL FOR SOME VALUES (XPATHS FROM CHROME)

```
import requests
from lxml import html

pageContent=requests.get(URL)
tree = html.fromstring(pageContent.content)
print(pageContent.content) #just to check the html string

TeamA_broken = tree.xpath('//*[@id="flashscore_column"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/span/a/text()') #get Team A: this does not work
print('Team A using lxml (empty): ' + TeamA_broken) #output []
TeamA_working = tree.xpath('//*[@id="flashscore_column"]/table/tr[1]/td[1]/span/a/text()') #get Team A: drop tbody and then it works
print('Team A using lxml (working): ' + TeamA_working) #output ['Hull']
Date_notworking = tree.xpath('//*[@id="utime"]/text()') #this does not work and the game date is empty in the html
print('Game date using lxml (empty): ' + Date_notworking) #output []
```

Can I get lxml to provide what I had with selenium?

Comment: If dropping the tbody helps that means that lxml is not in html5 mode while Firefox always is. You can try a html5 parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in page source `td` with `@id="utime"` is really empty. The value comes from variable declared in `script` node and it looks like `var game_utime = 1495375200;`. Not that this is *Epoch time* which can be converted to *human date&time* `May 21, 2017 5:00:00 PM`.

You can use regex to parse `script` node and extract epoch time and then convert it to required format as below

```
import time
import requests
from lxml import html
import re

pageContent = requests.get(URL).text

epoch_time =  re.search('var game_utime = (\d+);', pageContent).group(1)
date = time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M', time.localtime(int(epoch_time)))
print(date)
#  21-05-2017 17:00
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I am still at a loss around how to extract the for example second half score '1' for Team A (//*[@id="parts"]/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/span[1]) or '4' for Team B (//*[@id="parts"]/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/span[2]).  Hoping that if I crack these two, the many others that I am struggling to extract will fall into place (like odds, substitute names, etc etc).  I am clearly missing something.

Comment: @GivenX , this data (game stats) seem to come from XHR to https://d.soccer24.com/x/feed/d_su_C4RB2hO0_en_2, but currently I see no way how these two requests could be connected... But, wait, `C4RB2hO0` its just a game identifier, so you can just use URL template `url = "https://d.soccer24.com/x/feed/d_su_{}_en_2"` and pass the game id: `url.format('C4RB2hO0')`

Comment: Ok so all I had to do was save the html, then read it back in and everything works fine, no need to do anything with dates and all other values can be accessed via xpath.

Comment: `with open(r'HUL 1-7 TOT _ Hull - Tottenham _ Match Summary.html', "r") as f:
    page = f.read()
tree = html.fromstring(page)

output = tree.xpath('//*[@id="utime"]/text()') 
print(output)`